# Get the position of the 1st character of Nth field

Tags: awk

Lets say I want to get the position from left, i.e 7, of the 1st character of the 2nd field, i.e 'scripting', of the following line:

```
Shell scripting is amazing.
```

Please suggest some way, preferably using awk.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk and assuming you're using the default FS:

```
$ awk -v n=2 '{match($0,"[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"n-1"}"); print RLENGTH+1}' file
7
```

The `[[:space:]]*` at the front is to account for awk skipping leading white space before the first field given the default `FS`, and printing `RLENGTH+1` unconditionally is to ensure it always prints a number even if/when there aren't as many fields on the line as you're asking to find the start of (in which case it'd print `0`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, is there no built-in function, like index(), length() etc, for this kind of job ?

Comment: If you don't consider `match()` to be a built-in function for this kind of job then no, for a trillion builtin functions to do specific, obscure things (and the associated language bloat) you should look into [perl](https://www.zoitz.com/archives/13). The focus for the `awk` language has always been to only provide constructs to do things that are difficult to do with other constructs which is how they've kept the language so small, simple, clear, and easy to learn/use.